# changing streaming platform aspect ratio

Tags: console, video-streaming, aspect-ratio

is there any way to change aspect ratio on streaming platform through browser console editor ? since i have widescreen monitor and the aspect ratio is 21:9 and when i watching some movies that will be huge black border on the right left side even on the top bottom side cause the mainstream aspect ratio is 16:9[this is the example while i'm watching movie from HBO through firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faL1V.jpg)

i hope someone can solve my problem